# Jssor partial visible slider missing option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I'm adapting my code from the example

nearby-image-partial-visible-slider.source.html

It's working good except only one of my requirements is not met.

My images are ordered, so for the first image, I don't want there to be another image on the left of it (in the example it's the last image), and user shouldn't be able to swipe left any more if it's showing the first image. And the same for the last image, no image should be partially shown on the right. Is there an option to turn on/off the loop slideshow? If not, how may I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Please set `$Loop` option to 0.

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If I set $Loop to 0, there will be no image shown on the left side, for the first image it's what I need, but the same goes also for the next images. There is only the next image partially shown on the right, the previous image is never shown on the left of the current image. Any way to fix this?

Comment: good to know anyway. I will just wait for the next release. Thanks!